# Line 86: Char 2: runtime error: store to null pointer of type 'std::_Bit_type' (aka 'unsigned long') (stl_bvector.h)

Tags: c++, vector, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I'm trying Sieve of Eratosthenes and trying a problem in leetcode but I'm getting this error.

```
Line 86: Char 2: runtime error: store to null pointer of type 'std::_Bit_type' (aka 'unsigned long') (stl_bvector.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_bvector.h:95:2..
```

below is my code :

```
class Solution {
public:
    int countPrimes(int n)
    {
        int count = 0;

        vector<bool> prime(n, true);

        prime[0] = prime[1] = false;

        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
            if (prime[i]) {
                count++;
                for (int j = i * 2; j < n; j = j + i) {
                    prime[j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
};
```

I have tried finding solutions online but still unable to rectify it.

I know that error roughly means a index is getting out of bounds but I cant understand how?
please explain that.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  Second, Leetcode gives you the test case that doesn't fail.  What is the failing test case?  Third, your question could be downvoted because of the second item I mentioned -- a lack of debugging your own code will generate downvotes.

Comment: Presumably you first posted this question on the LeetCode forums.  Could you link to your LeetCode forum question, so we can read the answers there?  Thanks!

Comment: `for (int j = i * 2; j < n; j = j + i)...` - seems to me, from a cursory examination of the code, that `i * 2` could be past the end of the vector.

Comment: What if `n` is 1?  This: `prime[0] = prime[1] = false;` is already out of bounds.

Comment: @PaulSanders Except the condition is checked before loop iteration, not after. It will skip entire loop if `i * 2 >= n`.

Comment: [This is an example](https://godbolt.org/z/bvrn7fEz7) of a [mcve].  Instead of doing online searches, you should create such a program locally, test it, debug it.  As you can see, if `n` is 1, there is an issue.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Ah yes, silly me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't check `n` value before accessing `prime[0]` and `prime[1]`, `n` can be 0 or 1.

`runtime error: store to null pointer` is a clear sign that `n` is 0 (the vector does not have data, it's `nullptr` and vector's size is 0).